# Joomla 2.5 jroute trouble with localhost

Tags: php, joomla

I wrote a component and i have trouble using jroute for building links

Example : In my default tmpl in admin part,

if use $link = ''.JRoute::_( 'index.php?option=' . $option . '&task=tournoi.edit&id=' . $row->tournois_id );

or 
    $link = JRoute::_( 'index.php?option=' . $option . '&task=tournoi.edit&id=' . $row->tournois_id );

i get

```
http://joomla_new/administrator/index.php?option=com_tournois&task=generatereport&tid=1"  where localhost is missing.
```

if  i just add space like this : $link = ' '.JRoute::_( 'index.php?option=' . $option . '&task=tournoi.edit&id=' . $row->tournois_id );

i get

```
http://localhost/%20/Joomla_new/administrator/index.php?option=com_tournois&task=tournoi.edit&id=1
```

Anyone has an idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Do you have SEF Url's turned on in the Joomla backend?

Comment: Why are you prefixing your link with an empty set of quotes or a space as in your second example?

Comment: @cppl : i tried some things to see the pb.

Comment: @Lodder : yes it's turned on

Comment: Can you add the code where you're `echo`ing this into your `HTML` and the code for your router class so we can help.

Comment: Your question made me think of others solutions.
i finally fx it using the following code :
    $link = JURI::base().'index.php?option='.$option.'&task=tournoi.edit&id='.$row->tournois_id ;